# Why is everything in pyautogui exactly 1.5 times off?

Tags: python, image, pixel, pyautogui

I am writing a script using pyautogui and for some reason, the pixels seem to be 1.5 times off.
For example, when I use pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen on an image at the center of my screen, it returns the coords (960,540). But when 
`pyautogui.position()`, it returns the coordinates (1440,810) which is exactly 1.5 times larger than what it returned. When I do it on my laptop, everything is fine, but this problem is happening when I project my laptop screen on my connected monitor. Thanks!

Comment: Are the physical (hardware max. resolution), set resolutions and DPIs of the screens the same?

Comment: The hardware max resolution is 1920 x 1080 which is what I am using. I just tinkered with it and when I changed the scale of my monitor from 100% to 150% it seems to not have this problem anymore, but I don't like how the screen got bigger, but oh well, Thank you! https://imgur.com/a/OH8DkU2